# Expression for Color fill when date is between today and 7 days ahead

Tags: ssrs-2012

=IIF(Fields!IDX_Expiration_Date.Value > Today, "Yellow", "No Color")

I need to add less than 7 days ahead to the expression. So the condition is greater than today but <= 7 days from today.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use DateDiff to check the gap between today and your field value. If simpler using SWITCH too. Please try the following (untested) expression.

```
=SWITCH(
    Fields!DX_Expiration_Date.Value < Today(), Nothing,
    DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Today(), Fields!DX_Expiration_Date.Value) <=7 , "Yellow",
    True, Nothing)
```

Comment: Thanks Alan.  Works perfectly.  Will keep this in mind.